# Using mod for doubles on CGAL

Tags: cgal, modulo

I've been looking around on the web for this but cannot find anything.

Is there a way to use the CGAL::mod() function with 2 doubles? I can do 
`CGAL::mod(2,3)` but not `CGAL::mod(2.0,3.5)` for example.

I get errors like this on compiling:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(CGAL::Algebraic_structure_traits_base<double, CGAL::Null_tag>::Mod {aka CGAL::Null_functor}) (const int&, const double&)’
```

Am I doing something wrong? [From the documentation of the mod() function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_foundations/group__PkgAlgebraicFoundations.html#gac6bc445c0fc83ed997549ce869b7bae7) I understand that both arguments are of any tipe and that it can calculate it whilst compatible? I really don't understand that part, it's really technical but I hope you can help me.

Comment: The error message says `(const int&, const double&)`. Is one of your input argument an `int`?

Comment: Yeah but it happens when both are double.

Comment: `double` does not fulfill the requirements of the function.

Comment: Use `std::fmod`?